# Protractor / Jasmine timing out on headless chromium - Error: Timeout - Async callback

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Hi all so I am trying to run headless chromium with protractor and jasmine.  I have everything setup and working for both firefox and chrome with a head.  When I run firefox headless it works... when I try running chromium headless it ends up timing out.  Looking for some help to solve this problem.

The error I get is :

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Now I've read a million article online and have tried increasing the timeout time and adding done into the function as well...

Here is my current code:

Conf.js - this has a bunch of added args and settings that I've found online.  I've tried pretty much every variation and had no success..

```
  exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    allScriptsTimeout: 5000000,
    capabilities: {
        'directConnect': true,
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
            args: ["--headless", "--remote-debugging-port=9222", "--verbose", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-web-security", "--window-size=800x600"],
            'binary': "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
        }
    }
  };
```

Spec.js - straight off of their website with console.logs.  All of the console.logs print out in the following order 3,1,2.  This is something I'm unsure is correct?  Should the describe be waiting for the it to finish?  It almost feels like my it is never returning...

```
    describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function(done) {
    console.log("WOOO1");
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
    console.log("WOO2");

  }, 15000);
  console.log("WOO3");
});
```

Following this some other discoveries I have found... when I go to the localhost:9222 I see

```
   Inspectable WebContents
data:text/html,&lt;html&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

The data:text/html,<html></html> is a link and if clicked on takes me to the remote chrome debugger that is loading ... data:text/html,.  This is where I think the problem is.  Why is this never actually loading the angular site?

Maybe I'm off base but does anyone know how to make sense of this?

EDIT:
Additional useful information.
I am using 
chromium 79.0.3945.130
chromedriver 79.0.3945.36

jasmine v3.5.0
jasmine-core v3.5.0

Protractor 5.4.3

Thanks

Comment: The order of your console logs is correct. Any code within a spec file but outside of an It block will be executed before any It blocks begin execution. I know that can be confusing at first but just being aware of it is a first step. If you think you cannot load your site in headless chrome you should try adding some screenshots which will be saved and you can view after

Comment: I know the site is accessible as it's a public angular site and running in normal chrome works fine.  The concern raised is that protractor isn't replacing the data:text/html,<html></html> with the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config that ended up working for me

```
 exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    allScriptsTimeout: 9000,
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],

    capabilities: {
    'directConnect': true,
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
    args: ["--headless", "--remote-debugging-port=9222", "--verbose", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-web-security", "--window-size=800x600"],
    'binary': "path to chrome"
    }
    }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

add allScriptTimeOut in your configuration  like this:

```
exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['example_spec.js'],
    allScriptsTimeout: 9000
};
```

hope this link will help you
https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts.

Comment: Hi @Amato, I see you are a new user and just want to make you aware that link only answers are generally not considered very good answers. See this section in the FAQ on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information. While the info in the link may be useful to OP it would be better suited as a comment (which you do have enough rep to add now but hopefully will soon :D).

Comment: thank you @DublinDev for your comment , i already update my answer

Comment: I've tried this configuration as well and it doesn't fix it.  Any other ideas?  To me the test shouldn't run for more than a few seconds so setting this value at something like 30-40 seconds would be absurd and there is another driving factor to this as well...

Comment: @wdlax11 did u tried to use promise (then operator)?

Comment: No but I have it working somehow.  Generally I didn't change anything in my original config other than the jasmine going from jasmine 2 to jasmine

Comment: use promise with 'waitForAngular' can reduce time of appearance of this problem then if the application is very slow it is time to report performance issue